# snake game button functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pygame

i am making a snake game which i have completed but i m trying to make some levels in it like easy medium and hard for that purpose i have created my buttons like this

```
def button(msg, xposition, yposition, width, height, color, action = None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if click[0] == 1 and action!= None:
        if action == "play":
            another_screen()
        elif action == "easy":
            gameLoop_easy()
        elif action == "medium":
            gameLoop_medium()
        elif action == "hard":
            gameLoop_hard()
        elif action == "quit":
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (xposition, yposition, width, height))
    message(msg, black, xposition + 10, yposition +10, 50)
```

i have created a gameloop easy and gameloop medium and hard functions by copy pasting it and edited the lines used to increase snake speed. but it when i play the game it seems like action == "easy" is excutes only when i click on medium or hard it plays gameloop easy. Here is more code

```
def another_screen():
    another_screen = True
    while another_screen:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            screen.fill(white)
            border_design()
            message('Select Level', red, 20, 100, 100)
            button("Easy", 330, 290, 200, 65, green, "easy")
            button("Medium", 330, 390, 200, 65, pink, "medium")
            button("hard", 330, 490, 200, 65, blue, "hard")
            clock.tick(15)
            pygame.display.update()
```

i m unable to resolve this issue. Why button is not working why respected funtions are not being executed

Comment: you could assign function name to `action` - `action = another_screen` and then you can execute function `action()` without all these `if/elif`

Comment: you check if button was click but you don't check if it was clicked in "xposition, yposition, width, height" - and this is your big mistake. You can click in any place, not only in button and it will run function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your big mistake is that you don't check if it clicks in area `"xposition, yposition, width, height"`. You can click in any place on screen and it clicks button.

You can use [pygame.Rect()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to keep button's position and size and then you can use

```
rect.collidepoint(mouse)
```

to check collision. You can use `rect` also to draw rectangle.

I would also assign function to `action=` instead of text and then you can use `action()` instead of those `if/elif`

BTW: You also don't have to run `fill()`, buttons and other functions inside `for event`. You can use them after `for event`. Because you don't use `event` so you don't even need `for event`. But you have to use [pygame.event.pump()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) (instead of  [pygame.event.get()](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get)) because without this `get_pos()/get_pressed()` may not work.

```
def button(msg, x, y, width, height, color, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)

    if click[0] and action and rect.collidepoint(mouse):
        action()

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
    message(msg, black, x+10, y+10, 50)

def another_screen():
    another_screen = True
    while another_screen:
        pygame.event.pump()            

        screen.fill(white)
        border_design()
        message('Select Level', red, 20, 100, 100)

        button("Easy", 330, 290, 200, 65, green, gameLoop_easy)
        button("Medium", 330, 390, 200, 65, pink, gameLoop_medium)
        button("hard", 330, 490, 200, 65, blue, gameLoop_hard)

        clock.tick(15)
        pygame.display.update()
```

BTW: you can use `rect.collidepoint(mouse)` to change button color when mouse is over button (`"hover"/"unhover"`).

BTW: using `get_pressed()` you will have problem when on new screen you will have other button in the same place. It will changes screen and check button on new screen before you release mouse button - so it will click automatically in new button.

Comment: btw using classes you would not have to create pygame.Rect() again and again. Button's examples: [example1](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-change-stage), [example2](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-click-cycle-color), [example3](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/pygame/button-hover), [example4](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/button-change-stage/main.py)